# Probability of picking only good apple...

Tags: probability

There are 20 apples and 5 out of those are bad. I need to find out the probability of picking one good apple (2 apples are picked one after the other).

I have been able to solve using following:

```
P (both good) = 15/20*14/19 = 21/38
P (both bad) = 5/20*4/19 = 1/19
P (at least one good) = 1 - P(both bad) = 1 - 1/19 = 18/19
P (only one good) = P (at least one good) - P (both good) = 18/19 - 21/38 = 15/38
```

My question is, is it possible to come to the same result using probability tree?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. This is my first time asking a question. 2 apples are picked.

Comment: You can use the tree to compute the probability of "first good, second bad" and "first bad, second good", and sum the two probabilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be solve by tree diagram

$\text{P(good - good)}=\frac{15}{20}\times\frac{14}{19}$

$\text{P(bad - bad)}=\frac{5}{20}\times\frac{4}{19}$

$\text{P(good - bad)}=\frac{15}{20}\times\frac{5}{19}=\frac{15}{76}$

$\text{P(bad - good)}=\frac{5}{20}\times\frac{15}{19}=\frac{15}{76}$

$\text{P(good - bad) + P(bad - good)}=2\times \frac{15}{76}=\frac{15}{38}$